# How to pass value to controller and partial view via JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a system where the value within a text box is passed onto a partial view, where it will present the details corresponding to that value. So for instances if Job "1" was within the text box , the partial view will return the details of that job for the user to change etc. Any Ideas on how to pass the value to the controller then the partial view?

Job.js

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#qr-value').on('change', function () {
            if ($('#qr-value').val() == 'Job 1') {

                $("#second").show(1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

CameraInfo (partial view)

```
    model JobTracker.Models.Job

<h2>Edit and Confirm</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Job</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobID)

       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderID, "Order")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("OrderID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderID)
        </div><br />

      <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationID, "Location")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("LocationID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationID)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighPriority)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HighPriority, new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
            new { Value = "No", Text = "No" },
        },
         "Value",
         "Text",
        Model
    ))

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighPriority)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
        </div><br />

          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(
        new[] 
        { 
            new { Value = "In Progress", Text = "In Progress" },
            new { Value = "Completed", Text = "Completed" },
            new { Value = "Not Started", Text = "Not Started" },
            new { Value = "Stopped", Text = "Stopped" },
        },
         "Value",
         "Text",
        Model
    ))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
        </div><br />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Home Page", "Index","Home")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Job Controller.cs

//
        // GET: /Job/Edit/5

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);
        if (job == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);
        ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", job.OrderID);
        return View(job);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Job/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);
        ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", job.OrderID);
        return View(job);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id='Sample'></div>
```

if you want to load the partial view use ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qr-value').on('change', function () {
       $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "job")',
        data: { id: $('#qr-value').val()},
        success: function (response) {
        $('#Sample').html(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
        if (response.responseText != "") {
             alert(response.responseText);
             alert("Some thing wrong..");
           }
       }
     });
    });
});


 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
 {
  Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);
    if (job == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);
    ViewBag.OrderID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "OrderID", "OrderID", job.OrderID);

  return PartialView("Edit",job);
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Iceburg :) helped immensely! :) one question, you have a <div> sample at the start of your post....should this be put beside the HTML.partialview link?

Comment: that is the div you are going to fill the data after the ajax call. so put it where you want to display data and please mark the answer if it helps you.